# Can we use overview_polyline into waypoints of particular route duration

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using google direction service API to get route and it's distance with route drag option.

For example if i create a route between A & B. then i have dragged the original google given path to my own.

then i need to save my custom route (dragged route) and show the future reference.

In that case can i use  overview_polyline (direction response json node value) into waypoints to show exact my custom route.

Please help me

Comment: Before putting down vote. Please read once again and add comment to the related questionnaire. 
 Please avoid unnecessary "Down Vote"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can store the overview_polyline and later use it to draw a polyline which will restore your customized route.

To do this you will need a geometry library and call a `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath()` method to get the array of your points.

After that you can use this array to construct a Polyline object.

Please have a look at this sample code:

http://jsbin.com/kijaze/1/edit?html,output

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. :). but how can i send this overview_polyline into `directionsService.route(**directionrequest** `  to get route response from google api

Comment: DirectionsRequest doesn't work with encoded polylines. You can pass only origin, destination and 23 waypoints. You can try to pass the first point as origin, the last point as destination and select 23 points from the array to pass them as waypoints.

Comment: thanks xomena, i have completed the above task with simple trick. i have saved the steps json object. and while rendering the map i just replace the

Comment: @PalaniKumar are you able to share the trick code?

Comment: @Amitk Currently I don't have that code Sorry.